# Record IOS Screen and save video in document dirrectory

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, video-recording

I want to record IOS screen whatever rendering on it.

In my case my i am running 4 different video using 4 media player now i want to record screen and create one video of that screen.

I used AVCaptureSession but its working only for images and static screen.

I know its problem related to buffer and frame display which os is not able to capture or only capture black part.

looking for some suggestion or anyone who did it earlier.

Comment: Try to use RPScreenRecorder 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder

Comment: @oxigen it worked please mention in answer i will accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use RPScreenRecorder for it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder?language=objc